# Dump mysql_fetch_array results into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Thanks to all you gurus out there.

I am trying to make a previous and next button on a profile page.  If I am looking at the profile for Arnsdorf, I want a previous button to link to Antonio and a next button to link to Baldeviso.

IDs aren't sequential as you can see from the output which is ordered by lname:

```
ID: 22 Name: Airaghi
ID: 36 Name: Antonio
ID: 27 Name: Arnsdorf
ID: 13 Name: Baldeviso
ID: 46 Name: Barnes
```

Here's my code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id,lname FROM profiles ORDER BY lname";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$query) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row["lname"]);
          echo "<br>";
    }

mysql_free_result($query);
```

But I can't get it into an `array` to sort it.

I was hoping to create a 3 column `multi-dimensional array` with a data set that looks roughly like this:

```
row,id,lname
1,22,Airaghi
2,36,Antonio
3,27,Arnsdorf
4,13,Baldeviso
5,46,Barnes
```

I could then figure out how to get the number of the row for say Arnsdorf. Then get the row number for +1 and -1, so that I could get their respective ids for use in my hyperlink.

I have looked for hours and I can't find any code examples that will dump the mysql data into a numbered multi-dimensional array permanent enough to do this sort on.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assing each row to array, and then echo data from that array. Here is example:

```
$persons = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $persons[] = $row;
}

// To access ID of user in third row
echo $persons[2]['id'];
// Name of that person
echo $persons[2]['lname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $profiles[] = $row;
}
```

Now you will have an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => array('id' => 22, 'lname' => 'Airaghi'),
    1 => array('id' => 36, 'lname' => 'Antonio'),
    etc...
)
```

Then you can just access it from `$profiles[$index]['id']` or `$profiles[$index]['lname']`

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me with this explanation.